# Merge 2 Collections or Arrays by Key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying my best to prevent from looping over a collection to get more data that I need for a data table. I need a way to combine these 2 collections or arrays.

I have 2 functions inside a model that calls an API that gives me an array of data that I convert into a collection.

**Orders()**

```
public function orders(){
    $orders_array = $this->api()->request('orders.json');
    return collect($orders_array);
}
```

**Returns:**

```
Collection {#274 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
0 => {#282 ▼
  +"id": 628602961977
}
1 => {#270 ▶}
```

**order_meta()**

```
public function order_meta($order_id){
    $order_metafields_array = $this->api()->request('meta.json');
    return collect($order_metafields_array);
}
```

**Returns:**

```
Collection
#items: [
 +"name": "meta_data"
]
```

What I am wanting to do is inject the `order_meta()` into each order using the order ID.

**I guess I am wanting to do something like this:**

```
public function orders_detailed(){
        $orders = $this->orders();

        $keyed = $orders->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
            return [$item['meta'] =>  $this->order_metafields($item['id'])];
        });
    }
```

**In hopes it will return:**

```
Collection {#274 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#282 ▼
      +"id": 628602961977
      +meta => {
         +"name":"meta_data"
      }
    }
    1 => {#270 ▶}
```

Is something like this possible? I'm also open to merging it in as an array first, then creating a collection.

Comment: `array_merge()` is your friend

Comment: @FrankerZ `array_merge()` would only work if I loop over each order and then merge the meta array into it.

Comment: Did you look at the zip() method? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-zip. Also use mapSpread() on the zipped collection to perform some actions on the nested values.

Comment: And yes, I assume both the collections follow the same item index (order[0] corresponds to order_meta[0]). If that's not the case then looping over is the only way.